# Basic Conceptual query regarding Linked Lists

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm currently learning the basics of data structures and algorithms, and I've a doubt regarding creation and insertion of nodes in a linked list.

Till now, I visualized linked lists as bunch of nodes connected to each other; with a 'START/HEAD' pointer to the first node. But, when I came across Concatenating and Merging Linked lists, I got confused. I'm unable to understand the existence of 'multiple' linked lists in a program. Can't stop thinking about just a bunch of nodes connected to each other.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple linked lists?  Are you talking about several independent linked lists or a linked list with a linked list as its data?

Comment: If we're concatenating linked lists, there must be multiple linked lists in a program right? So I'm referring to independent linked lists in a program.

Comment: How come? Two linked lists can be completely independent. Each one is a chain of pointers from its own head. When you concatenate them, you link the `NULL` tail pointer of one to the first node of the other, and discard one head. When you merge, it is like a zip, you make a new list from nodes of the two input lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program can have several independent linked lists. A linked list starts with a head node to which many nodes can be connected and ends with last node pointing to NULL.

### Linked List Merge Illustration  :

```
Linked list 1 :  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
                 ^
                head pointer located at some memory x

Linked list 2 :  7 -> 8 -> 9 -> NULL
                 ^
                head pointer located at some memory y
```

After merging the two linked lists, we just make the head of one of the linked list as a regular node in the final linked list -

```
Merged Linked list : 1  ->  2  ->  3  ->  7  ->  8  ->  9  ->  NULL
                     ^                    ^ 
                    head pointer         used to be head pointer of Linked list 2
                    at some memory x     (now a normal node)
                (you still keep access
                 to this pointer)
```

And this is how the two linked lists which were independent will just be merged together. You will keep access to one of the head pointer and the other head pointer(of other linked list) will simply be merged into a normal node in the Final Linked list.

Hope you understand the above explanation of how linked list merging works.

Comment: Yes, I understood how merging works. But the doubt I'm still facing right now is how to create multiple linked lists in a program. There's a HEAD pointer to the first node. And then we keep on inserting nodes in the list. Where does the 'second' HEAD pointer come from?

Comment: @Rupesh If you have a second linked list, you must somewhere have created another pointer to a node(head pointer) in your program. A head pointer to a linked list is nothing but a variable which stores the address of the starting node of a linked list. You could very simply declare another node pointer and just start appending other nodes to it. That becomes your second linked list. The pointer which you declared at start was the second head pointer of second linked list.

Comment: You define one head pointer for each list, so `node *cakes;`  is the head of the list of cakes and `node *pies;`  is the head of the list of pies. Just like if you have two of anything, you just define another one.

Comment: Suppose you have a `struct Node` in C. If you declare a node like `struct Node* new_head` , that's a head pointer. Declare another as `struct Node* newer_head`, that's another head pointer. You can define as many of them as you need(as long as you have memory ofc). You just append similar nodes to this head pointer. A head pointer is just like any other nodes of a linked list but just special in the sense that you always maintain its address with you so you can get to any other node using your head pointer.

Comment: I get it now! Regards!

Answer (score 2):

A node is like a drink coaster. Now imagine a whole bunch of those coasters, strewn across the table:

[image: a bunch of coasters on an imaginary table]

You're free to connect them using lets say pieces of string and sticky tape.

[image: a bunch of linked coasters on an imaginary table]

I'm not showing the back-links that you'd have in a doubly linked list, since they add clutter. The discussion that follows is common to both singly- and doubly-linked lists.

It's obvious that all coasters (nodes) can be disconnected and completely lonely, or can be connected to a "predecessor" and "successor" - but such designations are completely arbitrary. If you have 10 coasters, they can form one linked list if they are all interconnected in a "line", or they can form 10 linked lists if they are not connected, or they can form any other number of linked lists between 10 and 1 - it just depends on how many are connected vs. not.

The process of merging/concatenating/splitting linked lists is simply the programmatic equivalent of adding pieces of string to connect the coasters.

The primary difference between coasters on a table and linked list nodes in C is that typical examples don't provide the "table": there's no common place where all the linked list nodes are available for inspection. With coasters we have the imaginary table they rest on (here: table is a piece of furniture, not a way of organizing information on a page).

So, the way you've likely been exposed to linked lists and their nodes - the vista is more like the below: an ugly green tablecloth covers most of the nodes. We just about glimpse of two of them sticking from underneath.

[image: a bunch of coasters presumably hiding under a tablecloth, with two sticking out from under the tablecloth]

The "table" definitely helps visualize things - without the tablecloth. Common C code used to "teach" linked lists looks exactly like this ugly green tablecloth:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node { struct Node *prev, *next; } Node;

Node *appendNode(Node *prev) {
  Node *newNode = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
  prev->next = newNode;
  newNode->prev = prev;
  return newNode;
}

int main()
{
  Node *first = appendNode(NULL);
  Node *last = first;
  last = appendNode(last);
  last = appendNode(last);
}
```

At this point we only "see" the first and last node in the list: they are the ones that "stick out" from under the tablecloth. I've made the tablecloth a bit transparent, but we don't really have a clear "handle" on the middle (second) node. We know it's there, we can imagine it being there, but it's only accessible via the links from other nodes:

[image: three nodes forming a linked list, mostly hidden under a semitransparent tablecloth]

Of course, this is just a way to badly teach the subject. There's no need for the tablecloth. You can create all the nodes directly, without any dynamic allocation. Here we create three nodes without any links:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node { struct Node *prev, *next; } Node;
int main()
{
  Node node1 = {}, node2 = {}, node3 = {};
}
```

The purpose of the initialization (`= {}`) is the same as the purpose of dynamically allocating the nodes using `calloc` rather than `malloc`: the last thing we want is uninitialized pointers. `calloc` initializes memory to zero, thus the pointers in the dynamically allocated nodes are NULL. Manual initialization via `= {}` does the same thing. No, you don't need anything inside the braces. You could write `= {NULL, NULL}` but that's unnecessary. The C language is defined to just zero-initialize everything if no values are provided in the initialization list.

Otherwise, it'd be rather easy to forget to initialize pointers, and such bugs can be hard to track down without proper tools that nobody bothers teaching in introductory material. If you were to use e.g. Asan (Address Sanitizer), uninitialized pointer dereferences would be caught immediately. But I bet nobody told you about Asan, even if it's free and not hard to use - so we must defer to defensive programming. That's always better than bug-chasing.

Now that we clearly see the three nodes, we can connect them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node { struct Node *prev, *next; } Node;
void connect(Node *from, Node *to)
{
  from->next = to;
  to->prev = from;
}
int main()
{
  Node node1 = {}, node2 = {}, node3 = {};
  connect(&node1, &node2);
  connect(&node2, &node3);
}
```

As you can see, it's easy to have any number of linked lists: if you have three nodes without any connections, they form three very lonely linked lists with just a single element each. But when you connect them together, you get a single linked list, even though the same number of nodes exist.

You can now add some additional nodes in their own list:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node { struct Node *prev, *next; } Node;
void connect(Node *from, Node *to)
{
  from->next = to;
  to->prev = from;
}
int main()
{
  Node node1 = {}, node2 = {}, node3 = {};
  connect(&node1, &node2);
  connect(&node2, &node3);
  // Create a second list
  Node node4 = {}, node5 = {};
  connect(&node4, &node5);
```

At this moment, the linked lists look as follows:

[image: two linked lists side by-side on the table]

Suppose we now want to "splice" this second between the 2nd and 3rd nodes:

```
  // Splice the new list between node2 and node3
  connect(&node2, &node4);
  connect(&node5, &node3);

  // Verify that the spliced list has the shape we expect:
  Node *const expected[] = {&node1, &node2, &node4, &node5, &node3, NULL};
  for (Node *toCheck = &node1, **stencil = expected; ;)
  {
    assert(toCheck == *stencil);
    if (!*stencil) break;
    toCheck = toCheck->next;
    ++stencil;
  }
}
```

[image: two formerly linked lists, now spliced into one]

And now it should be very clear how multiple linked lists can exist in the program. It'd be very easy to convert this single linked list into 5 separate ones:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node { struct Node *prev, *next; } Node;
void connect(Node *from, Node *to)
{
  from->next = to;
  to->prev = from;
}
void unlink(Node *node)
{
    node->prev = node->next = NULL;
}
int main()
{
  Node node1 = {}, node2 = {}, node3 = {};
  connect(&node1, &node2);
  connect(&node2, &node3);
  // Create a second list
  Node node4 = {}, node5 = {};
  connect(&node4, &node5);
  // Splice the new list between node2 and node3
  connect(&node2, &node4);
  connect(&node5, &node3);
  // Separate all the nodes
  unlink(&node1);
  unlink(&node2);
  unlink(&node3);
  unlink(&node4);
  unlink(&node5);

  // Verify that the nodes have no links
  Node *const toCheck[] = {&node1, &node2, &node3, &node4, &node5, NULL};
  for (Node *const *node = *toCheck; *node; ++node)
  {
    assert(!(*node)->prev); // idiomatic way of writing (*node->prev == NULL)
    assert(!(*node)->next); // ditto
  }
}
```

[image: the five formerly-linked nodes, now totally unlinked]

Now you'll ask: but hey, this is all nice, but what if we want to have a totally arbitrary number of nodes? Not necessarily 5, but, say, 500? What then? Should we write 500 `Node` variable declarations?

Well, you could just have an array:

```
Node nodes[500];
```

But that's not very flexible. What you'd typically want is some sort of a "handle" to the list - a way to "grab" the end nodes in the list.

Of course, this calls for a new data type:

```
typedef struct List { Node *first, *last } List;
```

Now we can write some functions that work using such a "handle":

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node { struct Node *prev, *next; } Node;
void connect(Node *from, Node *to)
{
  from->next = to;
  to->prev = from;
}
void unlink(Node *node)
{
    node->prev = node->next = NULL;
}

typedef struct List { Node *first, *last; } List;
Node *appendNode(List *list) {
  Node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
  if (list->last)
    connect(list->last, node);
  else {
    // the list is empty - there's no last node, and neither can there be a first one
    assert(!list->first);
    list->first = node;
  }
  list->last = node;
  return node;
}

Node *prependNode(List *list) {
  Node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
  if (list->first)
    connect(node, list->first);
  else {
    // the list is empty - there's no first node, and neither can there be a last one
    assert(!list->last);
    list->last= node;
  }
  list->first = node;
  return node;
}
```

That's great - now we can create the two lists:

```
int main()
{
  List list1 = {};
  appendNode(&list1);
  appendNode(&list1);
  appendNode(&list1);

  List list2 = {};
  appendNode(&list2);
  appendNode(&list2);
```

At this point, we got the lists separated:

[image: two linked lists, held by their "handles"]

And now we can splice them together:

```
  // Splice the new list between second and third node in list1
  Node *node2 = list1.last->prev;
  Node *node4 = list2.first;
  connect(node2, node4);
  Node *node5 = list2.last;
  Node *node3 = list1.last;
  connect(node5, node3);

  // Verify that the spliced list has the shape we expect:
  Node *const expected[] = {list1.first, node2, node4, node5, node3, NULL};
  for (Node *toCheck = list1.first, **stencil = expected; ;)
  {
    assert(toCheck == *stencil);
    if (!*stencil) break;
    toCheck = toCheck->next;
    ++stencil;
  }
}
```

[image: two lists now spliced]

Of course, at this point the `list2` handle is only semi-useful: it doesn't represent a stand-alone list. If we wanted to be precise about it, we could say that the following two invariants apply to "proper" list handles:

```
void checkHandle(const List *list)
{
  assert(!list->first == !list->last);
  // The list handle must either have no first and last element, or both (they may
  // be equal - we don't check that here.
  assert(!list->first || !list->first->prev);
  // Either the list has no first element, or the first element has no predecessor.
  assert(!list->last || !list->last->next);
  // Either the list has no last element, or the last element has no successor.
}
```

In light of such invariants, we'd need to immediately detach the `list2` handle from the elements, since they are a part of another list now:

```
  // after verifying that the spliced list has the expected shape
  list2->first = list2->last = NULL;
}
```

[image: The 5-element list with list2 head detached]